# How to programatically add items to navigation drawer and then handle their clicks?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I already searched thath i must do something like this:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
View view = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
menu.add("element");
```

But how to handle their clicks? I cant hardcode it, because they dont even exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener` interface for your `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` and catch a click on the programmatically added menu item:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        String itemName = item.getTitle().toString();
        if ("element".equals(itemName){
            //Do what you want...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
MenuItem item = menu.add("element");
item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
      //your logic

      return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I put this into a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a Other Views as Child of NavigationView

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
   <ScrollView>
         <LinearLayout>
         </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```